# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object when submitting a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got the error below and i don't know what's the problem is.
ValueError : The view bookmarks.views.bookmark_save_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Here is the code of bookmarks.views.bookmark_save_page :

```
def bookmark_save_page(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookmarkSaveForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        link, dummy = Link.objects.get_or_create(
            url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        )
        bookmark, created = Bookmark.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            link = link
        )
        bookmark.title = form.cleaned_data['title']

        if not created:
            bookmark.tag_set.clear()

        tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
        for tag_names in tag_names :
            tag, dummy = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_names)
            bookmark.tag_set.add(tag)

        bookmark.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            '/user/%s/' %request.user.username
        )
    else:
        form = BookmarkSaveForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'form' : form
    })
    return render_to_response('bookmark_save.html', variables)
```

The code of 'bookmark_save.html':

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}save your bookmark{% endblock %}
{% block head %}save your bookmark{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action=".">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

What is the problem? Did i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire code is indented under the `if` condition, so when the page is initially requested, no response is sent. You need to move the last `return` to the same level as the initial `if`:

```
def bookmark_save_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BookmarkSaveForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        link, dummy = Link.objects.get_or_create(
            url = form.cleaned_data['url']
        )
        bookmark, created = Bookmark.objects.get_or_create(
            user=request.user,
            link = link
        )
        bookmark.title = form.cleaned_data['title']

        if not created:
            bookmark.tag_set.clear()

        tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
        for tag_names in tag_names :
            tag, dummy = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_names)
            bookmark.tag_set.add(tag)

        bookmark.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            '/user/%s/' %request.user.username
        )
    else:
        form = BookmarkSaveForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request,{
        'form' : form
    })
  return render_to_response('bookmark_save.html', variables)
```

You can also further simplify your code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def bookmark_save_request(request):
    form = BookmarkSaveForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # .. your logic here
        return redirect('/user/%s' % (request.user.username,))
    return render(request, 'bookmark_save.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I've got an another error this time. UnboundLocalError at /save/ local variable 'variables' referenced before assignment, Exception Type: UnboundLocalError, Exception Value: 
local variable 'variables' referenced before assignment,

Comment: The only thing i modified is the last return to the same level as the initial if as you said.

Comment: That's because when the request method is not `POST`, the variable `variables` will never be defined, but will be used in the return statement. You can fix this by initializing `variables` to `{}` before your `if` statement. Though you may want to consider refactoring your code as suggested by Khalid.